angular unit testing: element.animate is not a function
I am trying to test mat snackbar. I have following code in my component.ts
snackbarRef: MatSnackBarRef<TextOnlySnackBar>;

constructor(private snackBar: MatSnackBar) {}

onUpdate(){
this.snackbarRef = this.snackBar.open(
        `Please select at least one option`,
        'Close',
        {
          panelClass: ['snackbar-failure'],
          duration: 5000,
        },
      );
}

I have following simple code in my test file component.spec.ts
describe('ExampleComponent', () => {
  let component: ExampleComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ExampleComponent>;
  let loader: HarnessLoader;

  beforeEach(waitForAsync(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ExampleComponent],
      imports: [BrowserAnimationsModule, MatSnackBarModule],
      providers: [MatSnackBar],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ExampleComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;

    fixture.detectChanges();
    loader = TestbedHarnessEnvironment.loader(fixture);
  });
  
    it('should should have no snackbar', async () => {
    expect(component.snackbarRef).toEqual(undefined);
  });
});

Unfortunately above code for testing gives error
TypeError: element.animate is not a function
at WebAnimationsPlayer._triggerWebAnimation (node_modules/@angular/animations/fesm2020/browser.mjs:4442:33)

When searching online, most solutions ask for to include either NoopAnimationsModule or BrowserAnimationsModule. Unfortunately both gives same error.
How can I fix this test?

You could try using NoopAnimationsModule instead of BrowserAnimationsModule
